# XSLT - Block has to fit table-cell

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

My problem is based on a table with two cells. If there is more text in the one cell, its getting expanded in down direction. In that case the other block is shorter (note that the table cell is as big as the other).

Basically I want to make a border around the table cell. But it shall be an image as a border. I'm making a padding in the table cell and the background color of the inside blocks white. With that strategy it looks kinda like a border. The problem is, that the block in the second cell is smaller, so there is more space beneath it. The border gets inconsistent.

[image: The output looks like this:]

Is there a way to scale the block to fit?

Comment: Do  you use XSLT to create a HTML table, a XSL-FO table? You will need to provide the details about the target format and the answer is probably not even specific to XSLT but rather to the target format.

Comment: Im making fo:tables. What else do you need to know?

Comment: Which FO formatter are you using? Also, is it always two columns and do you always know which column may flow over?

Comment: From the diagram, put the image in a block container and a table with white background inside

Comment: Im using antenna house and there are always two columns. I do not know which will be bigger, and i do not want to set a min and max height. Im reworking my whole code, and the purpouse is to get rid of tables in tables, due to some bugs. In my version before, I solved it like you said in the last comment. Is there no other way to do it? Big thanks!

Comment: Is the border a requirement? It's quite the eyesore, and does not contribute to making the text more legible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Antenna House, you can use `<fo:block-container column-count="2">` and add `break-before="column"` on the second `fo:block`.  See https://www.antennahouse.com/product/ahf64/ahf-ext.html#axf.column-count and https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#break-before

Comment: Wow. This actually works. Big thanks to you! I would've never found that solution. :)

Answer (score 1):

The block that contains the text in a cell is sized to fit the text. This is why your current background is uneven.
What you need is a background-color for the entire table: the table will be sized to fit the largest cell.

If the image is inside an fo:block, and this same block also contains the table, you get the result you want.

pseudocode:

```
<fo:block background-image="image.png">
    table goes here, with background-color="white" and a transparent border around the table to set the width/height of the visible portion of the background image.
</fo:block>
```

**Edit**: comments revealed more specifics.
With the added constraint that the border should be around the table header only:

1. Define the table without borders.
2. Insert the background image in the header cells.
3. Place the header cell text in a block with a margin of e.g. 5 mm on all sides.
4. For the body rows, also specify a margin to align the body text with the header text.

Comment: I actually tried to avoid tables in tables. But if there is no other way, I still have to say thanks! :)
I thought there may be an attribute to fit the table-cell, or an element that does that.

Comment: but you're not placing a table in a table, you're placing a table in a block.

Comment: It was ment to put a border around a table-cell. The border should be only around the header. In that case there is a table in a table. I don't think there is a workaround though.

Comment: Ah, I see. You can still do that without nested tables.